# ETL design for infrequent data load?

Tags: ssis, etl, business-intelligence

I have some data that need to load 3/4 times in a year and this process should include to existing package which run every day. As I can think of, I can disable the particular data flow task/sequence after run each time (3/4 times in a year).

should not be there some better way to design it?

Many thanks,
D. Paul

Comment: How do you know when the less frequent import should be run?

Comment: If you know when you have to run it, then simply use `execute sql task` and put up date conditional query which returns 1 or 0. Use this output to run your `execute package task` through condition.

Comment: @iamdave: It's delivered by email.

Comment: @prabhat G: Thanks for this, I thought about this process; however the file I get manually by email as .txt format; in this case; I am not getting the logical reason of making conditinal check before run the execute package task!!

Comment: If the file is delivered by email to a shared drive somewhere you can add a check of that location for the file and run the import when it is found.

Comment: In addition with @iamdave . All you need to do is download that txt file at some 'particular' location.

Comment: @iamdave, thanks ,  in this case, I have to delete the file from the shared location to avoid loading data again. I was thinking if I am able to detect if the package is run once then the particular sequence controller should be disabled for the 2nd time package start running so that I can avoid loading same data.

Comment: @Paul  Either add a timestamp to the emailed file which you check in your package or add the file management (ie: move processed file to `Archive` folder) to the end of your data import.

Comment: @iamdave : why to archive when you can delete the file ?

Comment: @PrabhatG  That is just one example of the *file management* I was referring to.  They may want to delete, they may also want to archive should they need to rebuild for any reason, they may also want to rename, etc.

Comment: Many thanks guys, I am creating share folder where business can load the file, and when file is exist in the folder then Data flow task will start, if no file is exist then data flow task will be skipped/disabled automatically.